# Rails: How can we detect which parameters is updated in CRUD controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I was just wondering: How can I identify which parameters is being updated in a classic CRUD controller?
I would like to redirect to different path depending on which parameters is being changed.

For example, if I have a `Person` with 3 attributes `id` `name` and `firstname`

In my controller:

```
def update
  @person = Person.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @person.update_attributes(params[:person])
      #...
    else
      #...
    end
  end
end
```

How can I detect that `name` is being changed, and not `firstname`

Would something like `!params[:name].nil?` work?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so you could check the params like you said. Something like `if !params.[:name].nil? ...`

OR

You could use the `_changed?` methods

```
@person.attributes = params[:person]
if @person.name_changed?
  next_path = name_changed_path
else
 ...
end
@person.save
redirect_to next_path
```

Comment: `_changed?` is cool, make sure you set the attributes on the object first as Jesse has done here with `@person.attributes = params[:person]` or by calling `update_attributes` as in Lucas' question first.